# WiFi-Direct communication between Mac/Windows and Android

Tags: android, windows, macos, wifi, wifi-direct

Is it possible to let an Android (>4.0) device establish a WiFi-Direct connection with a Mac OS or Windows device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Broadcast message from Desktop PC to Android Device using WIFI connectivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757665/broadcast-message-from-desktop-pc-to-android-device-using-wifi-connectivity)

Comment: isn't WiFi Direct, but perfect to share content from Android with it: [Share via HTTP | F-Droid - Free and Open Source Android App Repository](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.MarcosDiez.shareviahttp/)

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Wifi-Direct Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) the protocol allows:

> Android 4.0 (API level 14) or later devices with the appropriate hardware to connect directly to each other via Wi-Fi

It doesn't look like Google provides this functionality via the API. Although WiFi-Direct isn't a proprietary protocol and could be implemented for any platform. There are a few posts around the web of people trying to get Wifi-Direct to work under windows:

- [Broadcast message from Desktop PC to Android Device using WIFI connectivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757665/broadcast-message-from-desktop-pc-to-android-device-using-wifi-connectivity)
- https://superuser.com/questions/417888/how-do-i-connect-a-laptop-running-windows-7-to-an-android-phone-using-wifi-direct
- http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/wireless-products/my-wifi-technology.html
- http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/552970-howto-wifi-direct-use-your-laptop-desktop-softap-android-reverse-tethering.html

Answer (score -7):

All you need is to use java.net.Socket. Depends on what do you mean by establish direct connection. TCP connection is established when on destination device (windows or mac) you open listening socket by ServerSocket. On other device you can use Socket with destination address. Of course, windows or mac box will propably have to open that port in firewall.

I guess what you actually need to know is how to get name of target computer or how to discover computers on local network. Unfortunately, it does not depend on android version I think. You should check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking about some hints. I fear there might be problem in need to open privileged port on android, as normally you have to be root for that. And that would require rooted android.

Of course you should specify what do you intend with that direct connection and what software do you need. If both ends have your application, you can just open any not allocated and unpriviledged port on android. Use UDP to broadcast periodically name of android device (propably ask user to enter name of his device). Use multicast to send requests, and receive replies the same way. Multicast sending and receiving would require your application on android and on windows and on mac also. Now you can read from multicast application what type of machine it is, and what local port it left open for your direct connection. From source of udp message you know where to connect.

You may use some framework to speed things up. All this require some knowledge about networking, but I don't know simpler and well working solution. Unless you provide details about what is your direct connection to do.

Comment: The socket has to be only be established upon an existing WiFi-Direct connection. And this is what I am asking for, not the socket connection.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to setup a TCP-like connection on an already established network. Rather the OP wants to know how to use the WiFi-Direct protocol to establish a new network connection between a computer and a android device.